# What is the probability of choosing the same thing twice?

Tags: probability

In a jar of 70 Q-tips and I pull three from the center and put one back in the center and others take a total of six out of the jar before I pull more, what is the probability that I would pull that same Q-tip the next time I pull two Q-tips?

Comment: The pulling three and putting one back is irrelevant to the problem.  Imagine a jar of 68 qtips... one of which is red, all others white and you pull two.  The question is to find the probability you pulled the red.  It is $\frac{2}{68}$

Comment: @JMoravitz The jar starts with 70 I pull 2 but i guess you could say i touch one and it becomes the red one. It isn't just about a specific one but about it being the same one I pull twice.

Comment: Yes, and I don't care which of the 68 in the jar happened to be the one picked in the first step.  Whichever one it happened to be, I'll forget what its original label was and thereafter refer to it as "the red one."  The first step then happens in exactly the same way every time effectively

Comment: @JMoravitz Take into account that other people will randomly pull 6 before I pull the next two. If you have an answer please make an answer and not post it in the comments.

Comment: Also irrelevant.  Put them later in the stack and have them wait their turn until after you pulled again.  This is the same as how the second card in a deck is just as likely to be a queen as the first card in the deck, or indeed any other specific position is just as likely to be a queen as the first card in the deck.

Answer (score 0):

After pulling 2 Q-tips you now have 68 Q-tips inside the jar. The chance of others taking the Q-tip you put back in is $\frac{6}{68}=\frac{3}{34}$. We will call this event event $A$. After they take out 6 Q-tips there are 62 left. The chance of pulling the same Q-tip you put back in given it is still there is $\frac{2}{62}=\frac{1}{31}$. We will call this event event $B$. Probability B is just the chance of you pulling the Q-tip if the others didn't pull it. The chance of the others not pulling it is 1-P(A), so the chance of pulling the Q-tip is P(B)(1-P(A)). Therefore we have

$$(1-P(A))P(B)=\left(1-\frac{3}{34}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{31}=\frac{31}{34}\cdot\frac{1}{31}=\frac{1}{34}$$

Comment: This answer is good but it seems incomplete to me. It appears like the equation is assuming the Q-tip in question isn't pulled.

Comment: Probability B is just the chance of you pulling the Q-tip if the others didn't pull it. Obviously the chance of the others not pulling it is 1-P(A), so the chance of pulling the Q-tip is P(B)(1-P(A)).

Comment: Can you put that in the answer? I'm not great with math and equations.

Comment: I already explained this in the answer itself. I've made edits so hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Oh ok it wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The new starting point is 68 objects in the jar 1 of which ('X') was previously picked.

Others then pick 6 and you pick 2. We don't have any new information about X, which is equally likely to be in any of the 68 positions 60 in the jar, 6 with others, 2 in your hand). In 2 of those positions X is in your hand. Therefore the probability is $2/68=1/34$.

If we were told that X was not among the 6 picked by others, this is new information. X is equally likely to be in any of the remaining 62 positions (60 in the jar, 2 in your hand). So the probability of X being in your hand is now $2/62=1/31$.